# Opening different pages of app using cordova deeplinking

Tags: cordova, deep-linking

I am trying to apply deep-linking in my cordova android app but didn't able to make it work properly.

I have used [this link](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme#1-description).

Using this i am able to get my app launched on clicking on the page with link.

```
<a href="mycoolapp://">Open my app</a>
```

What do i have to do for providing links of other pages of app such as profile page, about us etc.

I have found the following configuration **json** file

```
  {
  "defaultRoute": {
    "class": "com.myorg.myapp.DefaultActivity"
  },
  "routes": {
    "reservations": {
      "class": "com.myorg.myapp.ReservationFeedActivity"
    },
    "reservations/:reservationId": {
      "class": "com.myorg.myapp.ReservationDetailsActivity"
    },
    "account/:userId": {
      "class": "com.myorg.myapp.AccountActivity"
    }
  }
}
```

**how to define such route and use in our cordova app.**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you found that json file, but it looks like it's intended to invoke intents in a native Android app, so isn't appropriate for use with a cordova app (unless your app has custom intents).

Looking at the [Usage](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme#3-usage) section of the Custom URL Scheme plugin, it looks as though you need to implement the `handleOpenURL(url)` function in order to perform custom routing your cordova app. It depends very much on which frameworks (if any) your app is built, as to how you'd do this.

For example, if your app uses [jQuery Mobile's](http://jquerymobile.com/) [page container](https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/) to manage different app screens, you could do something link this:

```
function handleOpenURL(url) {
  console.log("received url: " + url);
  var page = url.split("://")[1];
  $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", page+".html");
}
```

Then invoking your app by a custom URL such as `mycoolapp://somepage` would cause JQM to switch to `somepage.html`.